# Champagne and hechsher

Tags: halacha, minhag, sources-mekorot, grapes-wine, stam-yenam

I have heard (without a source) that some who were makpid to purchase only wines with hashgachot would consume wine from Champagne without a hechsher, probably because gentiles typically do not use such wines for religious purposes. Is there any basis for this custom, if ever it actually was documented?

Addendum: According to the reading that I have done on the subject, it was common to use particular [sweetened wines](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/dessert_wine)*, such as the Italian [Vin Santo](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/vin_santo), for sacramental purposes among Christians, as it was less of an acquired taste.

*I will not use sweetened wine for kiddush.

Comment: Per this article on [VosIzNeias](http://www.vosizneias.com/18724/2008/07/30/new-york-conservative-rabbis-fight-orthodox-kosher-state-laws/) conservative rabbis say that champagne without supervision and which do not bear labels/hekshers are acceptably kosher.

Comment: 2 commentless downvotes, oh my....I don't see what's wrong with this question.

Comment: I'd find such a position to be ironic in light of the fact that specifically Champagne is used these days for many "ship baptisms" or "ship christenings."

Comment: @IsaacMoses, ship christenings have nothing to do with the practice of baptising a Christian, it is merely a show of expensive waste when inaugurating a new ocean-going vessel.